# Prisma returns when i try to fetch something

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, prisma

I use prisma as ORM to build my expressJs API and when i try to fetch something, like a user below i have an empty JSOn as result. I don't understand because prisma has good access to my MySQL database (it mapped it well).

`

```
// route "/users"
app.get('/users/getAll', async (req,res)=>{
    const users = prisma.user.findMany();
    res.send(users);
});
```

`

I tried to use differents methods on differents table and i have the same result an empty JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing an `await`

```js
const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#findmany